# Responsive Menu with Text on Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive menu on top of an image background, which also has text on top.

Because I have to set the text messaqge with "`position: absolute`" to make it overlay on top of the background image, when I expand the menu the menu items will overlay on the text message. How do I fix that?

The other problem is I'd like to have the menu be transparent on the background image instead of being on the dark grey background. However, I can't seem to find a way to do that.

[Here's the code](https://jsfiddle.net/hoL986dp/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider for you header message to put it inside of your header-slides div and then position this div to relative.  That way your header message is actually positioned absolutely in the header and not in the body.  Then if you want your nav to be transparent over the header image then you can position your body to relative just to be safe and position your nav to absolute, give it a high z-index and background opacity can be achieved by using rgba colors.  So something like the following:

Here is a fiddle demo [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/81cqvdyc/)

Header:

```
.header-slides {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

<div class="header-slides" data-slides='["https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK1654.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30", "https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK2106.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30"]'>
  <h2>Header Message</h2>
</div>
```

Then your nav:

```
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(20,20,20,0.8);
  min-height: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:5;
}
```

And then remove the postion of relative from your responsive css at max width of 680px from your nav so remove the following completely:

```
ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
```

Comment: That's a very good solution, too. The only thing I'm concerned with is that if the number of my menu items is bigger, they will eventually overlay most of the background image. I'd prefer pushing down the background image so it doesn't overlay with the menu. So it seems if I just put the message inside of header-slides div and position the div to relative I can push down the background image. I'll look at your solution more closely to  make the nav background transparent. Thanks.

Comment: The only problem with pushing down the content with a tranparent background is that you will not see anything behind the transparent nav except for white if that makes sense.  So it will only make your nav background color look lighter but it will still look like a solid color.  Example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/m8k0t5f0/

Comment: You're absolutely right. I realized that once I start messing around the the color. I think I'm going to stay with the dark grey background and pushing down the background image. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), bruh.**

> When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other.
>   An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a
>   lower one.

`.topnav{z-index:9999999}`

[try it](https://jsfiddle.net/hoL986dp/2/).

---

For transparent BG colors you can use [rgba()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp). There are [online tools](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/) to convert your colors all oer the place.

Comment: I don't know why but I think I got confused by the text message on top so I thought the z-index didn't work. But you're right, it's just as simple as using the z-index. duh.....What about the background of the top nav? Is there an easy way to turn that into a transparent background instead of dark grey?